# In the following javascript code, why variable that is not accessible to func function?

Tags: javascript, function, scope

```
var func=function(){console.log(that)}
var obj = {
    foo(){
        var that=this;
        var a=func;
        a();
    }
}   

obj.foo();
```

**Result :**

*Uncaught ReferenceError: that is not defined*

Answer (score 0):

`that` only exists inside `foo` because that's where it's declared. Your `func` function is outside of `foo`, so the `that` variable doesn't exist there.

If you want to be able to access it in both places, you can declare it outside both functions:

```
var that;
var func=function(){console.log(that)}
var obj = {
    foo(){
        that=this;  // <-- no  var
        var a=func;
        a();
    }
}   

obj.foo();
```

Answer (score 0):

Because JavaScript uses lexical scoping, not dynamic scoping. That means variables aren't looked up in calling scopes at runtime. Only the nesting structure of the source code matters.

Comment: Is it appropriate to say that variable a just has reference to function?

Answer (score 0):

You don't have a reference to `that` in `func`. Either declare that as a **global variable** or pass it as an parameter to `func`.

**Option 1:** Passing `that` as a parameter

```js
var func = function(that) {
  console.log(that)
}
var obj = {
  foo() {
    var that = this;
    var a = func(that);
    //invoke function a like this;
    a;
  }
}

obj.foo();
```

**Option 2:** Declare `that` as a global variable

```js
var that;

var func = function() {
  console.log(that)
}
var obj = {
  foo() {
    that = this;
    var a = func(that);
    //invoke function a like this;
    a;
  }
}

obj.foo();
```